# reuse_alv_list events get the whole list as Excel

Tags: excel, abap, alv

I have a function module (`reuse_alv_list_display`) that I call in order to display my data so that the batch processing works right.

My problem is, that I add On top of the list some comments, and change a lot in the layout, like coloring the table.

I want to export the table as an Excel file (2007 using `zcl_excel_writer_2007` of [abap2xlsx](https://github.com/abap2xlsx/abap2xlsx)) but I do not know how to do this while keeping the formatting, that the user might have even changed.

Problem is, I don't know how, and in the examples they give, they use another method to display ALVs.

I saw elsewhere that it was somehow to get this table in the callback events, however I find it hard to find references for that.

My Question is: has anyone a solution how to export an Excel table with user formatting from ALV list...

PS: SAP ECC.

I already tried my original table (the raw data) problem is, that many of the ALV functions are different in Excel (eg. color table at end of each row).

Comment: This is a very old function module (nineties?), so I guess it doesn't generate an Excel file which looks like the displayed data. The latest `cl_salv_table` class will probably generate an Excel file which looks more like the displayed data. Note that you didn't explain what exact problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution proposed by Sandra is correct
I switched now to the newer cl_sal_table class based output, and so far do not regret it.
You can then just gife an instance of it to the exel builder of abap-tools and it will make an nice Exel File